# Error upon adding an array to List<String[]>

Tags: java, arrays, list

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String str = "a b c";
list.add(str.split(" "));
```

Basically I want an array of {a, b, c} however this isn't working. Do I have to iterate and load each element instead? How would I do this?

My error output looks like this:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@3d4b7453
[Ljava.lang.String;@24c21495
```

Comment: @RohitJain edited with output message.

Comment: Those aren't errors, those are the string representations of the arrays.

Comment: Not sure I am following, if you want array `{a,b,c}` what is the `List` for? Are you trying deliberately to populate the list with arrays?

Comment: @meiryo The code will work fine, and will give you a list with the specified array in it.. What did you expected?

Comment: @amit I have a bunch of strings with stuff like `a b c`. I want to loop through them and store it all in a list of arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works fine, but it looks like you're printing the wrong thing. Do this instead:

```
for (String[] strs : list) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strs));
}
```

Printing just an array will give you output like what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks. How do I reference the first element of an array in a list?

Comment: @meiryo `list.get(0)[0]` gives you the first element of the first array in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) to print elements of an array,

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.get(0)));
```

or alternatively iterate over them:

```
for(String s : list.get(0)) System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String str = "a b c";
list.add(str.split(" "));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.get(0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to print this way: -

```
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String str = "a b c";
    list.add(str.split(" "));

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.get(0)));
```

This prints: - `[a, b, c]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arrays.asList()

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String str = "a b c";
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split(" ")));
```

To print the result is like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```